# Stacked Bar in ng2-charts

Tags: angular, typescript, charts, stacked-chart, ng2-charts

I have gone through the documents of [ng2-charts](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/) but I couldn't find anything like `Stacked Bar`. Is there is any other way to achieve Stacked Bar chart in `ng2-charts`? Please help me out

Comment: In my opinion, you have to change settings of x and y axes in order to enable stacking in bar chart. See chat config options here  [https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/#BarChart], and on chart.js official documentation [https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's definitely supported, it is documented in the `chart.js` [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#stacked-bar-chart). You simply need to define which datasets are stacked together using the `stack` property on the `datasets` objects:

```js
public barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
  { data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'Series A', stack: 'a' },
  { data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Series B', stack: 'a' }
];
```

See this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-bar-stacked-example) for example.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to implement 'Horizontal & Vertical Stacked Bar Chart'
Use Chart 'options' to make it simple, check code.
In .ts

```
public barChartOptions = {
scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
responsive: true,
scales: {
  xAxes: [
    {
      stacked: true, 
      ticks: {
        stepSize: 1
      }
    }
  ],
  yAxes: [
    {
      stacked: true,
    }
  ]
},
```

};

In template

`<canvas  baseChart  [datasets]="barChartData"  [labels]="barChartLabels"  [options]="barChartOptions" [legend]="barChartLegend"  [chartType]="barChartType"> </canvas>`

check full code on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vertical-horizontal-bar-chart?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes